# Trace 0 and Norm 1 elements in finite fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-fields, traces, roots-of-unity

Let $\mathbb{F}_{q^\ell}/\mathbb{F}_{q}$ be the extension of finite filed $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, where $\ell$ be a odd prime and $(\neq q)$. Take $\zeta\in\mathbb{F}_{q^\ell}$. Does there exist different $i,j$ where 
$1\le i,j<\ell$ such that

$\hspace{5cm} Tr_{\mathbb{F}_{q^\ell}/\mathbb{F}_{q}}(\zeta^{1-q^i})=0$

and

$\hspace{5cm}Tr_{\mathbb{F}_{q^\ell}/\mathbb{F}_{q}}(\zeta^{1-q^j})=0$

Comment: The title of the questions mentions trace 0 and norm 1, but the question itself does not mention any norms.

Comment: Clearly not when $\zeta \in \mathbb F_q$. Also usually not for $\ell$ small, presumably. Or do you mean does there exist some $\zeta$?

Comment: I think it can be shown that for fixed $\ell, i,j$ the number of $\zeta$ satisfying these equations for $q$ large enough is $q^{\ell -2} + O( q^{ \ell - 5/2})$. So the total number of solutions is something like ${\ell -1 \choose 2} q^{\ell -2 } $.

Comment: @KConrad, maybe norm 1 is implicitly referring to the elements $\zeta^{1 - q^i}$?

Comment: @LSpice, Thank you. What you stated is true.

Comment: @WillSawin, Given $\ell$ and $\zeta$ does there exist $i,j$ with satisfying these equations ?

Comment: @sam Certainly not when $q$ is large with respect to $\ell$.

Answer (score 3):

No, not for every $q,\ell,\zeta$. In fact in general there does not even exist one solution.

Trivial example: $\zeta \in \mathbb F_q^\times$ implies $\zeta^{1- q^i} = 1$ and hence $Tr( \zeta^{1-q^i})=\ell \neq 0$. for all $i$.

Existence of nontrivial examples: If we multiply $Tr( \zeta^{1- q^i})$ by the norm of $\zeta$, it becomes a polynomial function of degree $\ell$ in $\zeta, \zeta^q, \dots, \zeta^{q^{\ell-1}}$. Indeed, we can write the trace as $\sum_{k=0}^{\ell-1} \zeta^{ q^k} \zeta^{ - q^{k +j}}$ where the sum $k+j$ is taken modulo $\ell$. The norm is $\prod_{k=0}^{\ell-1} q^k$ and by multiplying them we may clear denominators.

Each of $\zeta, \zeta^q, \dots, \zeta^{q^{\ell-1}}$ is a linear function of the $\ell$ coordinates of $\zeta$ in some $\mathbb F_q$ basis of $\mathbb F_{q^\ell}$. So the trace times the norm is a polynomial function of degree $\ell$ in those coordinates. Because it is not identically zero (as it is novanishing on elements of $\mathbb F_q)$ it has at most $\ell q^{\ell-1}$ solutions. Hence the total number of $\zeta$ for which there is some $i$ where this equation holds is at most $(\ell-1) \ell q^{\ell-1}$. For $q> \ell (\ell-1)$, this is much less than $q^\ell$ and so there are many points with no solution.